# Plotting the most recent data points with Seaborn scatterplot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, scatter-plot

I'm trying to plot the predicted vs actual of a stock using Seaborn's scatterplot, I can plot the scatter fine, but what I want to do is also visualise where today's data is, in a different colour.

I tried doing:

```
current_x = df['Prediction'].iloc[-1]
current_y = df['Actual'].iloc[-1]
```

and plotting that but got this error message :

`ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index.`

Any help would be really appreciated cheers.

EDIT:

So I have a `df` containing a `df['Prediction']` and `df['Actual']` columns of price data, the code to print the scatterplot I have used so far is very imple:

`sns.scatterplot(x='Predicted', y='Actual, data=data)`

What I'm looking for is just to also plot, on top of this original scatter graph, todays most recent data for x and y, so `.iloc[-1]` for each, if you will.

Comment: Please post [sample data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) even plotting code so we understand your process.

Comment: Hi mate, yep fair enough, have just edited it

Comment: take a look at matplotlib's [animation](https://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bit hacky, but this works.

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Prediction': np.random.rand(10), 
                     'Actual': np.random.rand(10)})

sns.scatterplot(x='Prediction', y='Actual', data=data)
sns.scatterplot(x='Prediction', y='Actual', data=data.iloc[-1].to_frame().T)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the argument `hue` when creating the scatterplot. If you don't have a `hue`, you can create one easily for your simple case:

```
data['hue']=[0]*(len(df)-1)+[1]
sns.scatterplot(x='Predicted', y='Actual', hue='hue', data=data)
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to use matplotlib directly instead of seaborn, it's very straight forward to plot all but the last point and the last point separately.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.DataFrame({'Prediction': np.random.rand(10), 
                     'Actual': np.random.rand(10)})

# Plot all but the last point
plt.scatter(x='Prediction', y='Actual', data=data.iloc[:-1])
# Plot only the last point
plt.scatter(x='Prediction', y='Actual', data=data.iloc[-1])

plt.show()
```

[image]